# Stack Overflow lost its mobile page?

Tags: bug, mobile-web

[image: Screenshot]

Apparently there's no mobile page for Stack Overflow anymore, every other SE site I've tried shows one. Using Chrome on Android 5.0.2 this has always worked but no longer shows a mobile page. Yes, I have tried everything from unchecking the "Desktop page" option to wiping my cache. If it's also relevant I'm not in any channels.

Comment: You can freely switch between mobile and desktop views with link in the footer, and the choice is set in a cookie. Simply switch back to the mobile view (last link in the footer at the left).